# Trouble installing Ubuntu server on old e-mail server

Tags: server, system-installation

So,
I got an old server that was being used as an email server running windows server 2003. For obvious reasons I want to change it to ubuntu server. I can get into the purple install screen, but after a couple set seconds (if I'm quick I can just about get after the language menu) it just doesn't accept input anymore and every key I press invokes a beep from the machine.

I flashed my usb with balena and it gave no errors when it finished.

Thank you,
Coolxm

Comment: Does the USB work properly if you boot a different machine with it?

Comment: @user535733, yes it does as far as I can see

Comment: The USB installer exhibits strange behavior ONLY on the one machine?

Comment: As far as I can see yes, I don't have another machine I can compromise so I just went to the install page but it never froze so I don't think anything was wrong

Comment: Then you seems to have conclusively demonstrated that your old machine is either faulty or otherwise incompatible with the USB. Perhaps it has a faulty USB port (it happens). Try booting the USB in a different port.